# default fallback of .resx properties when serializing to json

Tags: c#, .net, json, resx

When we use a `.resx` resource file, we usually have couple of languages per file.
For example:
`Settings.resx`, `Settings.he.resx`, `Settings.fr.resx` etc...

The `.net` framework will use the relevant file according to the current culture.
If a property is missing in `Settings.he.resx` it will search for it in the default `Settings.resx`.

This way we have a "base" resource file and we can override specific properties in different cultures.

My problem is that i'm serializing this file to `json` (for an `ajax` response) but i'm loosing the ability to fallback to the default files on missing properties.

Is there a way to preserve this behavior when serializing the object?
I prefer to keep the serialization simple and not to iterate over all the keys.

This is my serialization code:

```
protected JObject GetResourcesAsJsObject(ResourceManager resourceManager)
{
    var resourceAsDictionary = GetResources(resourceManager);
    var resourceAsJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceAsDictionary);
    var resourceAsJsObject = JObject.Parse(resourceAsJsonString);

    return resourceAsJsObject;
}
```

and using it like this (where `Settings` is a ref for `Settings.resx`):

```
var jsResources = GetResourcesAsJsObject(Settings.ResourceManager);
```